# ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have two dataframes:

```
import string
import pandas as pd

d = {'one': pd.Series(range(26), index = list(string.ascii_lowercase)),
     'two': pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], index = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

d2 = {'one': pd.Series(range(10), index = range(11, 21))}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
```

Now, I have a list of indices:

```
np.random.seed(12)
i = np.random.choice(np.arange(11, 21), size = 26)
```

Now I want to join `df2` with `df1` based on `i`.

```
df['new_col'] = df2['one'][i]
```

But I get the above mentioned error. One way to work around this is to add `i` directly to `df1`, and create a column called `i` in `df2` to represent the `index`, and then do a `merge` but it seems very inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

I know there are a few questions with the same title, but none of them had anything helpful for my case.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `tolist` method to convert your `df2.one` to list and then assign it to `df['new_col']`:

```
df['new_col'] = df2['one'][i].tolist()
```

**EDIT**

Or you could use `.values` attribute as @ajcr suggested in the comment which is faster:

```
df['new_col'] = df2['one'][i].values
```

**Timing**

```
In [100]: %timeit df2.one[i].tolist()
1000 loops, best of 3: 275 µs per loop

In [101]: %timeit df2.one[i].values
1000 loops, best of 3: 252 µs per loop
```

Comment: You could use `.values` instead, i.e. `df['new_col'] = df2.loc[i, 'one'].values`. Creating a list is more expensive than creating an array here.

Comment: @ajcr thanks, added to the answer. Timing shows that it's not so much faster

Comment: @Anton I bet it would with bigger dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

Set the index to use the values generated in 'i', then join df2 to df based on that index:

```
df = df.set_index(i)
df['new_col'] = df2['one']
```